throttle error when migration laravel 8 to 11
I made a migration from laravel 8 to 11 following the guides proposed in the doc, I find myself with a throtter problem when I try to reach my api sanctum and fortify :
error is :
[2024-12-11 10:47:30] local.ERROR: Target class [throttle] does not exist. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Contracts\\Container\\BindingResolutionException(code: 0): Target class [throttle] does not exist. at /home/yannick/dev/NetDesk/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:879)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/yannick/dev/NetDesk/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(758): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build()
#1 /home/yannick/dev/NetDesk/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(851): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve()
#2 /home/yannick/dev/NetDesk/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(694): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve()
#3 /home/yannick/dev/NetDesk/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(836): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make()
#4 /home/yannick/dev/NetDesk/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(206): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make()
#5 /home/yannick/dev/NetDesk/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->terminateMiddleware()
#6 /home/yannick/dev/NetDesk/backend/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->terminate()
#7 /home/yannick/dev/NetDesk/backend/server.php(21): require_once('...')
#8 {main}

[previous exception] [object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class \"throttle\" does not exist at /home/yannick/dev/NetDesk/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:877)
[stacktrace]
#0 /home/yannick/dev/NetDesk/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(877): ReflectionClass->__construct()
#1 /home/yannick/dev/NetDesk/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(758): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build()
#2 /home/yannick/dev/NetDesk/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(851): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve()
#3 /home/yannick/dev/NetDesk/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(694): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve()
#4 /home/yannick/dev/NetDesk/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(836): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make()
#5 /home/yannick/dev/NetDesk/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(206): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make()
#6 /home/yannick/dev/NetDesk/backend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(180): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->terminateMiddleware()
#7 /home/yannick/dev/NetDesk/backend/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->terminate()
#8 /home/yannick/dev/NetDesk/backend/server.php(21): require_once('...')
#9 {main}
"} 

//backend/app/Http/Kernel.php
 protected $routeMiddlewareAliases = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'type.customer' => CustomerMiddleware::class,
        'type.tech' => TechnicianMiddleware::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'role' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\RoleMiddleware::class,
        'permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\PermissionMiddleware::class,
        'role_or_permission' => \Spatie\Permission\Middlewares\RoleOrPermissionMiddleware::class,
    ];

some api routes :
Route::get('getTicketCategories', [DataController::class, 'getTicketCategories']);
Route::get('getPlanificationTypes', [DataController::class, 'getPlanificationTypes']); 
Route::get('getDashboardPoints', [DataController::class, 'getDashboardPoints']);

When I did some research, it was about a defect in the kernel but I added the file and still the same error. Do you have any idea how to find the cause or solve it?

fix : renaming routeMiddlewareAliases to middlewareAliases in kernel file
